# Call overload method with default parameters

Tags: c#, call, parameter-passing

Suppose we have two methods

```
public void foo(int a, int b, bool c = false)
{
    //some code
}

public void foo(int a, int b, bool d, bool c = false)
{
    //some other code
}
```

when I call `foo(1,2,true)` it refers to first method. Is there any way to call second method by passing only 3 parameters?

I found something like this in production code :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo(1,2,d:true); //will call the second method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Named parameter is just a parameter, with *default* value.

In *your* presented code you simply `overload`. Note the amount of parameters (non named) is different.

Other question could be:

Can I do something like this ?

```
public void foo(int a, int b, bool c)
{
    //some code
}

public void foo(int a, int b, bool c = false)
{
    //some other code
}
```

Answer: no, you can not. Because, as I said, named parameter, is just an ordinary parameter with default value, so this will not compile, as there is already one method with *exactly* same signature.